# Get just numbers from a list Content HTML

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers, parseint, getelementsbyclassname

Currently I am starting a Project in Javascript its a Game cards, I wanna get just the numbers from the list
no string just Ints numbers [text](https://dhardi.github.io/pokebatlle/)

[image]

I want to take just numbers from a list HTMl no string. I try to convert to parseInt but I know when get the element return as array just with the quantity of class I do not have the content

```js
power = document.getElementsByClassName("power").innerText;
let opNum0 = parseInt(document.getElementsByClassName("power")[0].innerText);
let myNum3 = parseInt(document.getElementsByClassName("power")[3].innerText);
console.log(myNum3);

if (myNum3 > opNum0) {
  alert("you win");

} else {

  alert(myNum3);
  scoreCountYou()

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/6r8auL3o/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try this

```
let opNum0 = parseInt(document.getElementsByClassName("power")[0].innerText.replace(/\D/g,''));
let myNum3 = parseInt(document.getElementsByClassName("power")[3].innerText.replace(/\D/g,''));
console.log(myNum3);

if(myNum3 > opNum0){
    alert("you win");
}else{
    alert(myNum3);
    scoreCountYou()
}
```